# String.replaceFirst does not replace the expected string sometimes

Tags: java, regex

Using java i try to replace occurence of certain string with other one. It works in most of the cases. But sometimes that certain string is not replaced in the given content.

When i search that certain string in the given content using indexOf method, i can correctly get the index of that String. But when i use replaceFirst method to replace that String, the operation ends with unsuccess.

Then i tried to replace using following in order to escape from escape characters.

```
cont = Pattern.compile(str, Pattern.LITERAL).matcher(cont)
    .replaceFirst(Matcher.quoteReplacement("replace string"))
```

Lets us take below content as example

> For the pictures of animal please
>   visit this site
>   http://www.example.net/animals/cat_345_456.JPG
>   . Also more details visit this link
>   also
>   http://www.moredetails.com/example/imgs/nwr_1453446_83223_429054_1603367_42.PNG?Id=1450686&lid=423454&idp=4402767&ps=4563223&circle=4&type=2&zw=264&zh=150&v=5&url=NA&uid=
>   . Thanks visiting us.

In the above content First i assign str with value of http://www.example.net/animals/cat_345_456.JPG and then i call replace first method.

In this case expected string replaces correctly.

Then now i assign str with value of http://www.moredetails.com/example/imgs/nwr_1453446_83223_429054_1603367_42.PNG?Id=1450686&lid=423454&idp=4402767&ps=4563223&circle=4&type=2&zw=264&zh=150&v=5&url=NA&uid= and i call replace first method.

But this time it doesn't got replaced. But when i use String.indexof method it correctly gives index number of that String.

Am i missing anything?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A short but complete example would make this *much* easier to help you with.

Comment: What happens if you `quoteReplacement(str)` instead of using `Pattern.LITERAL`?

Comment: Your sample works for me. Both, the first and the second replacement. Which Java version do you use?

Comment: @OrangeDog there is no difference after removing pattern.literal @morja i'm using jdk1.6.0

Comment: @Sathish can you post the whole code you are using?

Comment: the posted code works fine with the given texts (assuming no newlines/other hidden chars) under JDK 1.6.0 - the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: s. Now only i noticed. Sometimes the value cont contains & and sometimes it contains &amp; But the value of str contains only &. how can i handle this? please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine for me... here's my test code:-

```
public class StringReplaceTest {

    public static String replaceMe(String str) {
        String cont = "For the pictures of animal please visit this site http://www.example.net/animals/cat_345_456.JPG . Also more details visit this link also http://www.moredetails.com/example/imgs/nwr_1453446_83223_429054_1603367_42.PNG?Id=1450686&lid=423454&idp=4402767&ps=4563223&circle=4&type=2&zw=264&zh=150&v=5&url=NA&uid= . Thanks visiting us.";
        return Pattern.compile(str, Pattern.LITERAL).matcher(cont).replaceFirst(Matcher.quoteReplacement("replace string"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testOne() {
        String str = "http://www.moredetails.com/example/imgs/nwr_1453446_83223_429054_1603367_42.PNG?Id=1450686&lid=423454&idp=4402767&ps=4563223&circle=4&type=2&zw=264&zh=150&v=5&url=NA&uid=";
        String actual = StringReplaceTest.replaceMe(str);
        String expected = "For the pictures of animal please visit this site http://www.example.net/animals/cat_345_456.JPG . Also more details visit this link also replace string . Thanks visiting us.";

        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }

    @Test
    public void testTwo() {
        String str = "http://www.example.net/animals/cat_345_456.JPG";
        String actual = StringReplaceTest.replaceMe(str);
        String expected = "For the pictures of animal please visit this site replace string . Also more details visit this link also http://www.moredetails.com/example/imgs/nwr_1453446_83223_429054_1603367_42.PNG?Id=1450686&lid=423454&idp=4402767&ps=4563223&circle=4&type=2&zw=264&zh=150&v=5&url=NA&uid= . Thanks visiting us.";

        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in cases that it does not work your search target contains some special characters that make sense for the patterns. For example ()[]{} etc. This stuff must be escaped using backslash. But Jon is right: short example explains and helps much more.

Comment: Thats why i used Pattern.literal in order to escape special characters.